# Reactivating Windows 10 OEM guest after transferring from Xen to Virtualbox

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, virtualization, windows-activation, xen

I had a Windows 10 Pro (OEM) installation running as a guest on a Xenserver 6.5 host.  The host has crashed and I copied the VHD file directly from the host to another host running Virtualbox.  I was able to boot with no problems, but Windows now reports that it is not activated.
I called Microsoft's activation line, but they imply that the product key is invalid and won't assist in reactivation.

Is there anything I can do to re-activate the machine as a Virtualbox guest?  It would be a *huge* amount of work to try and rebuild the Xen server and move everything back to it.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: How can you run an OEM license inside a virtual machine? OEM licenses ship with a pc.

Comment: Not within the licensing agreement, since OEMs are only licensed to the hardware they were shipped with.  MS doesn't support OEM licensing in VMs.  The OEM licensing will look at your setup and see you've got entirely different hardware (albeit virtual) and fail to activate.  Always use retail licenses in VMs.  You should be able to purchase a new key and activate that on your "new" hardware.  Moving back to Xenserver "should" let you reactivate since the hardware will be similar.